# How to find missing orders in Magento

Tags: orders, sales-order, magento2.2.3

When I check the orders were placed on our site in the Magento admin panel, some of the order numbers are missing or we can say there's no sequence in order number.

**Example**: Magento was at number 100034468 and the next order number that came in was 100034470. The number 100034469 is missing.

So I don't know what happened to that missing order number. I have read some of the posts in Magento community, they are all saying that this can happen If there is session error or the transaction was declined to the order. Because of this, the order number will not be used again.

Unfortunately, there's no payment log under the **var** folder in order to check about the failed transaction.  I want to know what happened to the missing order number.

I hope that I will get a satisfied answer from you. Looking forward to your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is a problem in Magento. You can't solve it out of the box but can be done with some tweaks in the code or you can use this [extension](https://www.fmeextensions.com/find-missing-orders-extension-for-magento-2.html) to get it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You will simply not get those orders,

because they are not exists

whenever some customer initiate the checkout process a unique order incrementid is assigned to them

but if they fail to put order and in mean time some other customer place the order that order increment id will be skipped

and you will no longer see that order increment id's order.

Comment: For checking purpose, I pretended to get stuck in the checkout by not selecting the payment method and finally closing the browser (on the computer that opened the site + checkout first). and meanwhile finished the second computers order (which should get the next ID increment).

The result is that it does not jump over the number. If it did work that way it would have added an unused ID between order 10 and order 11 which it did not.

As per your information, I have tried to verify and do exactly the thing you are specifying but it is not giving the output.

Comment: Instead if a customer fails in Payement Gateway, it will show up as pending payment or canceled, and if the order is failed in the last part of the checkout that it will not show up at all (and just continue with the correct ID in the sequence). So now, I'm confused with this. Please help me to understand why the order number skips randomly. Thanks.

Comment: @Siva did you manage to get the issue?